# Oracle sub error on query

Tags: sql, oracle

Following code I added to the SQL Server query and now have to do the same in Oracle. I need to do grouping in the view rather than in the C#. I get this error message:

> ORA-01747 Invalid user.table.column or column specification.

How must I code this to work in Oracle?

```
SELECT CTE.FACILITY_KEY, CTE.DATE, CTE.PATIENT_STATUS, COUNT(*) AS [COUNT]
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY CTE.FACILITY_KEY, CTE.DATE, CTE.PATIENT_STATUS;
```

at the beginning of query I have this full code here:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DBD_V_CDL_CHANGES AS 
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT TR.FACILITY_KEY
       , MV.VALUE_CODE
       , CAST(COUNT(*) AS NUMERIC(9, 0)) COUNT
    FROM OPTC.THS_T_TRANSACTIONS1 TR
    JOIN OPTC.THS_M_MENU2 M
      ON M.MENU_ID = TR.MENU_ID
    JOIN OPTC.THS_M_VALUES MV
      ON MV.MENU_ID = TR.MENU_ID_VALUE
    JOIN OPTC.THS_M_VALUES MV2
      ON MV2.MENU_ID = TR.PREVIOUS_MENU_ID_VALUE
    JOIN OGEN.GEN_M_PATIENT_MAST PM
      ON PM.PAT_NUMBER = TR.PAT_NUMBER
   WHERE TR.TR_DATETIME BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                            AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 86399 / 86400
     AND TR.EDIT_NO < 0
     AND MV.VALUE_TYPE IS NULL
     AND MV2.VALUE_TYPE IS NULL
     AND MV.VALUE_CODE >= 0
     AND MV2.VALUE_CODE >= 0
     AND M.SUB_SYS_EXT = 'G1'
     AND ABS(MV.VALUE_CODE - MV2.VALUE_CODE) > 1
     AND (PM.DISCHARGE_DATE IS NULL OR PM.DISCHARGE_DATE < SYSDATE)
   GROUP BY TR.FACILITY_KEY, MV.VALUE_CODE)

   SELECT CTE.FACILITY_KEY, CTE.DATE, CTE.PATIENT_STATUS, COUNT(*) AS [COUNT] FROM CTE
  GROUP BY CTE.FACILITY_KEY, CTE.DATE, CTE.PATIENT_STATUS;
```

Comment: The view definition is not complete. Do you mean to be querying from the view, `DBC_V_CDL_CHANGES`?

Comment: Also see [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01747.php) for an explanation of ORA-01747. It usually means you're trying to use a reserved word as a column.

Comment: CTE or COUNT not reserved word.

Comment: maybe this is not the way to do in both sql server and oracle? maybe just plain group by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few things wrong with your code.

First, you are selecting the following three columns `FACILITY_KEY`, `VALUE_CODE` and the count in the `CTE`:

```
SELECT TR.FACILITY_KEY , 
    MV.VALUE_CODE , 
    COUNT(*) as Count -- note there is no need to CAST(COUNT(*) AS NUMERIC(9, 0)) this
FROM OPTC.THS_T_TRANSACTIONS1 TR
```

But then when you select from the `CTE` you are selecting columns that you are not returning in the CTE:

```
with cte as
( 
  -- your query here does not return DATE or PATIENT_STATUS
) 
SELECT CTE.FACILITY_KEY, 
    CTE.DATE, 
    CTE.PATIENT_STATUS, 
    COUNT(*) AS COUNT 
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY CTE.FACILITY_KEY, CTE.DATE, CTE.PATIENT_STATUS;
```

Where do `PATIENT_STATUS` and `Date` come from since you are not including them in your `CTE`? So these do not exist when you are trying to select them.

I replicated your error by including columns in the list that were not select in the CTE query.

The second issue is the `CTE.DATE` column. `DATE` is a reserved word, place that is double quotes `CTE."DATE"`

Comment: they come from the main query. You have these columns are the results: FACILITY_KEY, DATE, PATIENT_STATUS

Comment: @Booksman the columns you return in `select ... from cte` must be in the main query and they are not in yours. You are only returning 3 columns in your main query.

Comment: @Booksman See my edit. The `DATE` column is a reserved word and needs to be in double quotes.

Comment: @bluefeet - This is not Oracle syntax and will never work - ...AS [COUNT], ...AS NUMERIC(9, 0)). Please fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

...AS [COUNT], ...AS NUMERIC(9, 0)) is not Oracle syntax and will never work. Simply remove [ ] and use NUMBER instead of NUMERIC. There is no need to CAST Count(). The Count() function will always return number, e.g. 0-zero or some number.

This is valid syntax in Oracle:

```
SELECT deptno, count(*) total_count_by_dept -- no need to cast or AS --
  FROM scott.emp
GROUP BY deptno
/
```

Try not to use reserved words as COUNT for aliases:

```
SELECT CTE.FACILITY_KEY, CTE.DATE, CTE.PATIENT_STATUS, COUNT(*) AS total_cnt -- 'AS' is for clarity only, not required
  FROM CTE
 GROUP BY CTE.FACILITY_KEY, CTE.DATE, CTE.PATIENT_STATUS
/
```

Comment: The cast as numeric does work. I tested it and it is working in Oracle 11g and in this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8498/3